# Problem Running script with variables

Tags: shell-script, variable, read

I have a script that will install WordPress this is my first attempt at scripting so I wanted to try something simple.

Centos 7

2 Problems

First 3 lines of script take user input:

```
read -p "Enter the site name without the TLD: " $sitename
read -p "Enter the TLD: " $tld
read -p "Enter 3 letter prefix: " $siteprefix
```

Problem #1 Creating the database

```
mysql -u root -pPassword -e "CREATE DATABASE ${siteprefix}db"
```

I am looking for 'CREATE DATABASE mngdb' given the siteprefix = mng

It will create a database with the name db

Problem #2

```
/usr/sbin/adduser -d /var/www/$sitename-$tld/ $siteprefix+=ftpusr
```

Error adduser: invalid user name '+=ftpusr

What I am looking for is to create a user mngftpusr given the siteprefix = mng

Any help on how to format the above two lines so they will work in the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are including the dollar sign when setting your variables.

Your reads should look like this.

```
read -p "Enter the site name without the TLD: " sitename
read -p "Enter the TLD: " tld
read -p "Enter 3 letter prefix: " siteprefix
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer that fixed problem #1 however problem #2 i am getting a different error adduser: invalid user name 'mng+=ftpusr'

Comment: @AnthonyFornito AFAIK `bash` does not have such a string concatenation operator: however you can use `${siteprefix}ftpuser` (just like you already did for `${siteprefix}db`)